# What does the phrase "the outer circle" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Context:

> At 06:10 yesterday, on **the outer circle** of the capital city highway in Minato District Tokyo a traffic collision occurred, involving five cars and at least one truck."

What does "the outer circle" mean?

The only thing that comes to mind for me is that it has something to do with a beltway.

> Beltway TFD def: A high-speed highway that encircles or skirts an urban area. Also called belt highway.

Comment: Beltway is right.

Comment: Beltway seems very American... I'd say ringroad (or orbital motorway perhaps) in BrE

Comment: Check out images of "London inner and outer roads"

Comment: This is a very specific usage and the question is rather out-of-place here IMO. Looking at [a map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuto_Expressway#/media/File:Tokyo_Metropolitan_Expressway_map-en.svg) my guess is that it refers to the "C2" loop. In any case, there are two loops, one smaller and one larger; "the outer loop" obviously refers to the larger one.

Comment: Michael Harvey@ So "outer circle " "beltway" &"ring road" ARE ALL  synonyms?

Comment: Can't find any online dictionary that would list "outer circle" as a synonym for beltway ;/  What I was thinking was that the road in question is a beltway indeed and "the outer circle" means that it's the part of the road that skirts the city and the "inner circle" would be the part that goes through the city.